# Navigate And Remove List of Objects in JLabel

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, keylistener

my test project is a list of numbers from 1~5 and show in `JLabel` and when press arrow key
change `JLabel` text and show list index and if press remove key remove label number and show next index
of `AarrayList`.

method for add objects to list:

```
private List<Integer> numList() {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (list.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                list.add(i);

        }

        return list;

    }
```

method for show objects in `JLabel` :

```
private void showNum(List<Integer> list, int index) {

        String num = "-";
        int size = list.size() - 1;

        if (index >= 0 && index <= size)
            num = list.get(index).toString();

        label.setText(num);

    }
```

and (my problem) delete item:

if index of object less then list size after remove show next object
and when index equals size of list show Previous Object (if size > 0):

```
private void deleteNum(List<Integer> list, int index) {

        int size = list.size() - 1;
        boolean validIndex = (index >= 0 && index <= size) ? true : false;

        if (validIndex)
            list.remove(index);


        System.out.println(size);
        System.out.println(list);

        showNum(list, index);
    }
```

and code for navigate in list :

```
private void navigate() {

        List<Integer> list = numList();

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

                int key = event.getKeyCode();

                switch (key) {

                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

                    if (index < numList().size() - 1) {

                        index += 1;
                        showNum(list, index);

                    }

                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

                    if (index > 0) {

                        index -= 1;
                        showNum(list, index);

                    }

                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

                    if (index < numList().size() - 1) {

                        index = numList().size() - 1;
                        showNum(list, index);

                    }

                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

                    if (index > 0) {

                        index = 0;
                        showNum(list, index);

                    }

                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE:

                    deleteNum(list, index);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

this is a test project and my main project is Image viewer...

### Update

i change `numList()` method and first create a global var `List list;`
and new method :

```
private void initList() {

        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                list.add(i);

        

        

    }

``

now problem is when delete last object first time show Previous object but secend time show "-"

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/URIQw.png
```

Comment: What's is the exact error that happens?

Comment: if delete any of objects add "-" to last of  shown label  when run : 1 -> 2 -> (delete) 3 -> 4 -> 5  result : 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> "-"  if delete 2 object add 2 "-"  It adds to the end and other problem is : when delete last object not shown Previous object and show "-"  and when remove `if (validIndex){...}`  show `IndexOutOfBoundsExeption`

Comment: Some remarks: there is no sense in testing `if (list.isEmpty()) {` for a freshly created list. Of course, a list just created via `new ArrayList<Integer>()` is empty. Further, don’t use statements like `boolean variable = condition? true: false;`. The condition is already a boolean expression, so just use `boolean variable = condition;`. Your problem stems from the inconsistency of `numList()` creating a new list every time. At the beginning of `navigate()`, you declare `List<Integer> list = numList();`, but then, you sometime use that list, but at other times call `numList()` again.

Answer (score 0):

Your list was always being recreated in every numList() call. So by turning it into a class variable and changing the calls of numList().size() into list.size(), it seems to work:

```
private int index = 0;
private List<Integer> list;

public Frame() {
    initComponents();

    navigate();
}

private List<Integer> numList() {

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (list.isEmpty()) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

    }

    return list;

}

private void showNum(List<Integer> list, int index) {

    String num = "-";
    int size = list.size() - 1;

    if (index >= 0 && index <= size) {
        num = list.get(index).toString();
    }

    label.setText(num);

}

private void deleteNum(List<Integer> list, int index) {

    int size = list.size() - 1;
    boolean validIndex = (index >= 0 && index <= size);

    if (validIndex) {
        list.remove(index);
    }

    System.out.println(size);
    System.out.println(list);

    showNum(list, index);
}

private void navigate() {

    list = numList();

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            int key = event.getKeyCode();

            switch (key) {

                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    if (index < list.size() - 1) {

                        index += 1;
                        showNum(list, index);
                    }

                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    if (index > 0) {

                        index -= 1;
                        showNum(list, index);
                    }

                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    if (index < list.size() - 1) {

                        index = list.size() - 1;
                        showNum(list, index);
                    }

                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    if (index > 0) {
                        index = 0;
                        showNum(list, index);
                    }
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE:
                    deleteNum(list, index);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```